Power Query- Nested functions and IF statements
I need to add a column to a nested table with values based on a condition.
Each field in the new column "Hybrid Value" should get the value of field "AlutMufchetetColumn", if the value of ID equals "Meyuadot"
This is the code, I think I still can't get my head around the passed on variables and scopes.

You can see the numbers under Hybrid Value, which are taken from Column Alutmufchetet, only when the values of ID include the string "AlutMuf"
ShoviHibrid=

      let
         X= Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(IDandKvutsa, (r)=>

         Record.TransformFields(r, {"CSV Table With ID and Kvutsa", 
         (TableField)=>

        Table.AddColumn([CSV Table With ID and Kvutsa],{"Hybrid Value",              

              if Text.Contains(TableField[ID],"Meyuadot" ) then

                        "Success" else "not success"  })

               })))

     in

         X


@horseyride see my edited post. Let me know if I need to provide more details.

I edited the code too, to remove unnecessary steps. I will add them later.

IDandKvutsa is the main table. In column "CSV Table With ID and Kvutsa" I have the nested tables. What I'm trying to do, is transforming the fields in "CSV Table With ID and Kvutsa" to add columns to the nested table.

The table above is the nested one. The first half of the code deals with fetching the filed with the table, the second half adds a column to the nested table. I think I miss something about records transformation and passing variable through the functions

I figured it out, my main mistake (among others) was the {} in the AddColumn function.
This is how it should look like:
   ShoviHibrid=

      let
         X= Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(IDandKvutsa, (r)=>

         Record.TransformFields(r, {"CSV Table With ID and Kvutsa", 
         (TableField)=>

        Table.AddColumn(TableField,"Hybrid Value", (SubRecord)=>             

              if Text.Contains(SubRecord[ID],"Meyuadot") then

                        "Success" else "not success"

              )})))

     in

         X

